# Форма chm чтение в php

Tags: php, chm

Столкнулся с банальной, кажется проблемой. Но не могу найти ничего с документацией и примерами. При этом формат кажется от Microsoft и значит как минимум чтение должно быть обеспечено как следует. То есть, чтение должно быть доступно без проблем и бесплатно... Но вот как его читать не понятно.

Если кратко - нужно файл превратить в большой ассоциативный массив, сохранив структуру. То есть в ключах, например, есть главы и далее по глубине. А в конце массив с контентом ... Потом уже все взять, как удобнее. Но проблема в том, что ничего очевидного не нашлось.

Вопрос - что есть для этого? Может проще попробовать самому и формат для чтения проще, чем я буду все искать долго и нудно?

Comment: Попробуйте готовые решения, например, [CHMLib](https://github.com/mlocati/chm-lib#chmlib---read-chm-files-from-php)

Comment: По данным википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTMLHelp (где кстати перечислены библиотеки для работы с этим форматом) из недостатков выделена "Недокументированность", что в общем то закономерно, потому как Microsoft всю жизнь делал закрытые форматы, которые мог читать только он сам...